Finding Zeros of $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (\sinh(z)+\sin(z))$ in $\mathbb C$
I am attempting to show that the zeros for this function lie upon two lines within the complex plane, furthermore I am to show that the zeros asymptotically approach an arithmetic progression. So far I have attempted to rewrite the expression as a power series which is of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{ 4n+1 }}{\left(4n+1\right)!}$$ from this I attempted to shift the function over with a substitution so that it looks more like the form of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\cdot\frac{z^{4n+1}}{\left(4n+1\right)!}$$ which demonstrably has zeros on the real line instead of just in the complex plane. From this though I am only getting rather nasty formulas that aren't giving any insight. For example I am getting that the alternating series is equivalent to the expression $$1/\sqrt{2}\cdot(\cos(z/\sqrt{2})\cdot\sinh(z/\sqrt{2})+\cosh(z/\sqrt{2})\cdot \sin(z/\sqrt{2}))$$
however even online computational tools are not helping me progress further. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Perhaps there is a much simpler way to approach the asymptotic behavior of this function.

From a complex plot, also visualized here, the zeros are possibly $z=(1\pm i)a_k$.

I can show that $f(z) = \frac 12 (\sinh(z) + \sin(z))$ has infinitely many zeros on the two lines $\operatorname{Re} z = \pm \operatorname{Im} z$, and that these zeros approach an arithmetic progression in any of the four directions towards infinity.
I assume that $f$ has no other zeros, but I haven't been able to prove that yet.
Let us consider the function
$$
 g(z) =  f((1+i)z) \, .
$$
An elementary calculation shows that
$$
 g(z) =  \frac{1+i}{2} \bigl(\cos(z) \sinh(z) + \cosh(z) \sin(z) \bigr) \\
 = \frac{1+i}{2} \cos(z) \cosh(z) \bigl( \tanh(z) + \tan(z)\bigr) \, .
$$
It is not difficult to see that $g(z) \ne 0$ at the points where $\cos(z) = 0$ or $\cosh(z) = 0$, therefore the zeros of $g$ are exactly the zeros of
$$
 h(z) = \tanh(z) + \tan(z) \, .
$$
For $x \in \Bbb R$ is $h(x)$ strictly increasing on each interval $(k\pi - \pi/2, k\pi + \pi/2)$, $k \in \Bbb Z$, with limits $-\infty$ (resp. $+\infty$) at the left (resp. right) endpoint of each interval. It follows that $h(x) = 0$ has exactly one solution $a_k$ in $(k\pi - \pi/2, k\pi + \pi/2)$. Also $\tanh(x) \to \pm 1$ for $x \to \pm \infty$ implies that
$$ 
 a_k \sim k \pi - \pi/4 \text{ for } k \to +\infty \\
 a_k \sim k \pi + \pi/4 \text{ for } k \to -\infty \\
$$
So $h$ has zeros on the real axis at the points $a_k $, and (since $h(iz) = ih(z)$) also on the imaginary axis at the points $ia_k$.
This proves that the original function $f$ has zeros on the lines $\operatorname{Re} z = \pm \operatorname{Im} z$, at the points
$$
 \frac{\pm 1 \pm i}{2} a_k \, , \, k = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots 
$$
and for $k \to +\infty$ the zeros are asymptotically located at
$$
\frac{\pm 1 \pm i}{2} \left( k \pi - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\, , \, k = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots .
$$

Owing to the given power series form, the function $f(z)=\frac12(\sin z+\sinh z)$ can be expressed as $f(z)=z E_{4,2}(z^4)$ where $E_{\alpha,\beta}$ is the Mittag-Leffler function. Ignoring the trivial zero at the origin and substituting $z^4 \mapsto z$, the question of therefore amounts to finding the complex zero distribution of $E_{4,2}(z)$.
The problem of the zero distribution of $E_{\alpha,\beta}$ is unfortunately altogether nontrivial, and a description for $all$ $\alpha,\beta$ does not seem to be available. But some results are known, as summarized on pages 72-73 of Gorenflo et al's 2014 monograph on Mittag-Leffler functions along with relevant citations therein. In particular, Theorem 4.12 indicates that the complex zeros of $E_{\alpha,\beta}(z)$ are simple and negative (real) so long as $\alpha>2$ and $\beta\in(0,2\alpha-1]$. This is certainly true for $(\alpha,\beta)=(4,2)$, and therefore the complex zeros of $E_{4,2}(z^4)$ must have $z^4\in (-\infty,0]$. The claim for $f(z)$ then immediately follows.
The full statement of Theorem 4.12 further gives inequalities on the locations of these zeros, whereas Theorem 4.11 provides asymptotic formulae for various cases of $\alpha>2$. Both are stated without proof and attributed to Popov and Sedletskii 2013. These presumably reproduce the results provided by Martin R.

Indeed, the condition for Theorem 4.12 applies to all $\alpha>2$ if $\beta=2$. Hence one immediately can give analogous statements for the zero distribution of $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{\alpha n+1}}{(\alpha n+1)!}$$ under the above condition.
